# Will garden giant mushrooms survive in a normal septic tank?

Tags: waste, mushrooms

I've heard that garden giant mushrooms will breakdown fecal matter, and was wondering if it would be a good idea to put some inside the septic tank to have it break down fecal matter to make it less necessary to suck out the septic tank.

How do I do this without destroying the septic tank?

Paul Stamets did something similar above ground: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SSKQyMFw8GM

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It wouldn't work in a normal septic tank. Normal septic tanks tend to get anaerobic as resident bacteria use up all the oxygen very quickly. This would prevent fungal mycelium from surviving since they do require oxygen - even though they can do well with lower levels than we could. In addition, bacteria are far more suited for breaking down organic matter with high nitrogen like septic inputs. Mushrooms are more competitive in lower nitrogen substrates - like a pile of wood chips.

I imagine that you could solve the oxygen problem fairly easily, but then you'd also be improving the bacteria's ability to deal with the fecal matter. Basically bacteria are a much better processor of septic waste than fungi.